# how to get check setState function callled or not in react js using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks

I am trying to test `custom hook`. I want to know is `setState` function fire or not.
here is my custom hook

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export default () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://5os4e.csb.app/data.json");
    setState(res.data);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fetchData();
    })();
  }, []);

  return { state };
};
```

now I am trying to test this `custom` hook.  I want to know is `setState` function fire or not .

I tried like this

```
import moxios from "moxios";
import React from "react";
import { act, renderHook, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";

import useTabData from "./useTabData";
describe("use tab data", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
  });

  describe("non-error response", () => {
    // create mocks for callback arg
    const data = [
      {
        name: "hello"
      }
    ];
    let mockSetCurrentGuess = jest.fn();
    beforeEach(async () => {
      moxios.wait(() => {
        const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
        request.respondWith({
          status: 200,
          response: data
        });
      });
    });

    test("calls setState with data", async () => {
      React.useState = jest.fn(() => ["", mockSetCurrentGuess]);
      const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useTabData());
      console.log(result);
      //expect(mockSetCurrentGuess).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not mock the React internals. This is incorrect. Either ways, this code has no effect in mocking due to closures.  Even if it worked, no point in testing if you are mocking the real implementation, isn't it ? :)

I would recommend to try to get grasp of what react hook is doing in your code.

You have a state in your custom hook:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);
.
.

return [state]; //you are returning the state as ARRAY
```

**@testing-library/react-hooks** allows you to debug and get value of current outcome of hook.

```
const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useTabData());
const [foo] = result.current; // the array you returned in hook
expect(foo).toEqual('bar'); //example assertion
```

I would stop here and allow you to learn and debug.

Comment: so what to test ??

Comment: sorry to late reply ...!! could you please tell me what are things i will test in thus function

Comment: I already gave the answer! You might have to go through some basics to get you upto speed.

Comment: ok ,,thanks but can i check updated state value after promise resolve ?

Comment: after promise it should have `array of object` intead of blank array